# Can I calculate average factor loadings from Cronbach's alpha?

Tags: correlation, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, cronbachs-alpha

I was wondering if I could post hoc calculate the Fornell-Larcker criterion to assess discricimant validity given the correlation matrix between several subscales and Cronbach's $\alpha$ for each subscale.

My thought-process is the following:

Fornell-Larcker compares the square root of the average variance extracted (AVE) of each subscale with the correlation of that subscale with all other subscales. The logic of this method is based on the idea that a construct should share more variance with its associated indicators than with any other construct.

The AVE is defined as the grand mean value of the squared loadings of the indicators associated with the construct (i.e., the sum of the squared loadings derided by the number of indicators).

Thus, I need the mean loading of the indicators associated with a given subscale.

**So my question is:** Can I calculate this mean loading from Cronbach's $\alpha$?

Cronbach's $\alpha$ is basically a function of the average interitem correlation and the number of items that constitute a scale. 
So if I know Cronbach's $\alpha$ and the number of items that are associated with the scale, I also know the average interitem correlation.

So the more precice question is: can I calculate the mean loading from the average interitem correlation?

The "Handbook of Research Methods in Social and Personality Psychology" says I can (p.479; available [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=72fLAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA479&lpg=PA479&dq=relationship+between+inter-item+correlation+and+factor+loading&source=bl&ots=OEm5oQjMs0&sig=nEvh8SIz0NBtPZD87GIdhqupVcY&hl=de&sa=X&ei=CSHbVNXoLo3CPI-RgagM&ved=0CGYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=relationship%20between%20inter-item%20correlation%20and%20factor%20loading&f=false))

There, it states that the factor loading (of a CFA) equals the square root of the mean interitem correlation.

Is this correct? I always thought computing the factor loadings was a somewhat more "sophisticated" process.

I also tried to simulate this procedure with some of my own data, and the square root of the mean interitem correlation came close, but was not identical to the factor loading computed by Amos.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
Correlation item 1 with item 2: 0.487308
Correlation item 1 with item 3: 0.482797
Correlation item 2 with item 3: 0.468675

Mean interitem correlation of item 1: 0.4850525
Mean interitem correlation of item 2: 0.4779915
Mean interitem correlation of item 3: 0.475736
```

The resulting square roots (which should be identical to the factor loadings) are:

```
item 1: 0.696457106
item 2: 0.691369294
item 3: 0.689736181
```

Using the same data-set in AMOS to compute a CFA with these three items results in the following factor loadings:

```
item 1: 0.694
item 2: 0.674
item 3: 0.696
```

As you can see, this is (pretty) close, but not identical.

The average (which is what I would need) is even closer:

```
Average calculated from mean interitem correlation: .69264
Average calculated from AMOSfactor loadings: .688
```

**So, my final question is:** Is it possible to calculate the (average) factor loadings in the proposed way? If it is, are the differences observed in my sample data negligible or have I made a mistake?

Or, is it not possible and I am either misinterpreting the "Handbook of Research Methods in Social and Personality Psychology" or is it indeed wrong?